# How to create a button in the corner of a panel in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a button at the corner of a panel by bootstrap.

I'm trying to achieve something like this, so if anyone knows how, please give code or reference.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the bootstrap site, where your screenshot is from, there is an element with a class `zero-clipboard`, with a child element with a class `btn-clipboard`

Those elements have the following styles, I've only copied what's relevant.

```
.zero-clipboard {
    position: relative;
}
.btn-clipboard {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: in getbootstrap.com'source view, there is no btn-clipboard. and any code for this one. Do you know how to work in getbootstrap.com?

Comment: Good call. I inspected the example code on the bootstrap website but the .zero-clipboard div actually lives outside the example panel.

Answer (score 0):

that is actually a flash component

```
 <embed src="/assets/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1405420608963" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" height="100%" name="global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="trustedOrigins=getbootstrap.com%2C%2F%2Fgetbootstrap.com%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fgetbootstrap.com" scale="exactfit">
```

if u want to have that corner button make a fluid div and add follwing code for the button

```
   #buttona {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
   }
```

HTML markup

```
   <div  class="container container-fluid">
   <button id="buttona" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">clickme </button>
   </div>
```